# Ajax IntelliSense not working in vs2013

Tags: ajax, visual-studio-2013, intellisense

In my web forms project I have IntelliSense working for jQuery, so that for example when I type "$(", I immediately get a nice list of possible arguments. I've tried following similar steps to set up IntelliSense for ASP.NET Ajax, but so far typing "$find(" (for example) gives this warning:

"IntelliSense was unable to determine an accurate completion list for this expression, The provided list contains all identifiers in the file"

I'm not sure what files I need to copy to my project's scripts directory if any. I've added quite a few references in Tools-Options-Text Editor-Javascript-Intellisense-References Implicit (Web), (everything in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\JavaScript\References), so far nothing works.

Answer (score 1):

The file need include jquery.js in project.

Comment: <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>

Comment: Put the script tag in the answer so it becomes clearer.

Comment: The question is not about jQuery, it's about ASP.NET Ajax.